# What should i put on my resume as i have left the business to my other partners?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, project-management

I had started a business in partnership and after 7 months left it and it is still running. How can I fill up this gap on my resume?

Comment: whyyyyyyyyy is there a gap? You were at a business in a partnership... doesn't sound like a gap to me.

Answer (score 1):

You were occupied there, so just list it and be prepared to answer questions like "Why did you leave it?", "Under what terms did you leave it?", "How's that business now?", in addition to the usual questions like "What did you contribute?".

Note: *I* do not quite understand the term 'in partnership', but it may be clear where you come from. If not, change the wording.

How to list it? Something like "2012-2013 Company X - Partner".